# Fixed position entries in console log

Tags: javascript, debugging, console.log

Is there a way to write fixed position entries in console so that
they are seperate from the scrolled area ?

e.g

```
console.reserve(2); // top 2 lines

console.txt(0,"current value="+currentVal());
console.txt(1,"current time="+currentTime());
for(var i=0;i<100;i++) console.log("scrolling "+i);
```

the scrollable area skips the first 2 lines

I searched and found no such thing

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that... console.group might be useful for you though.